# How to add a custom "More Posts" button to Blogger hompage

Tags: templates, blogger, custom-code

I am creating my my own custom blogget tenplate.I'm fetching posts to my blog using b:loop and want to fetch only 4 or 5 posts in one page/hompage. so it will make my blog load faster. but then I need a "More Posts" button to view the other posts list as 4 or 5 per page.so can you help me to do this?
what code do I need? demo of more posts button blogger:

[image]

Comment: Please share your codes here.

Comment: i don't have a code for this button.

Comment: can i use data:blog.newerPageUrl  ???

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this shortcode :

```
<data:posts[i].oldestLinkUrl/>
```

More info about this  in this article

https://bloggercode-blogconnexion.blogspot.com/1973/08/Blog-data-posts-oldestLinkUrl.html